# Генерация Excel файла под Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: uwp, windows-mobile

Вопрос в следующем: есть SDK 15063, ARM архитектура. Существуют ли библиотеки генерации excel отчетов для Windows 10 Mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) работает на чистом .NET

Comment: При попытке добавления через NuGet ругается:
Ошибка NU1202 Пакет EPPlus 4.5.3.2 несовместим с uap10.0.15063 (UAP,Version=v10.0.15063) / win10-x86. Пакет EPPlus 4.5.3.2 поддерживает:
  - net35 (.NETFramework,Version=v3.5)
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
  - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

Comment: Спасибо [IMil](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361311/imil) все получилось